# Best way to check that in a binary representation of number all set bits are followed by unset bits only

Tags: java, data-structures, bit-manipulation, time-complexity

Could you please let me know is there any best way to find that in binary representation of this number set bits are followed by unset bits only like - 
4 - 100
6 - 110
8 - 1000
12 - 1100

```
private static boolean setBitFollowedByUnsetBits(int num) {
    String str = Integer.toBinaryString(num);
    int len = str.length();
    int countof1 = str.indexOf('0');
    int lastIndOf0 = str.lastIndexOf('0');
    int countof0 = lastIndOf0 -countof1;
    int lastIndOf1 = str.lastIndexOf('1');

    if((!(lastIndOf1 > countof1) && (lastIndOf1 < lastIndOf0))) {
        return ((num >> countof0+1)==((2 << countof1-1)-1));
    }   
    return false;
}
```

This is what the logic i have written but i am looking for better solution which is much efficient .

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Is `1100` OK or not? Or do you mean that there is only one group of set bits, and `11001100` is illegal?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Alberto's hint:

You are looking for a bit pattern like 0000 0000 0111 1111 1100 0000 0000 0000 (I assume 32-bit integers):

- some leading zero-bits (none is also OK)
- a block of one-bits (at least one)
- a block of zero-bits (at least one)

Special cases can be all zero-bits (N==0), or a number ending with a one-bit (having no trailing zero-bits). Let's first look at the generic case:

Having a binary number like N=xxxx1000, then N-1 is xxxx0111, replacing all the trailing zero-bits by one-bits, the rightmost one-bit by a zero-bit, and leaving the higher bits unchanged.

ORing N with N-1 like `int K = N | (N-1);` replaces trailing zero-bits with one-bits:

```
N   = xxxx1000
N-1 = xxxx0111
      --------
K   = xxxx1111
```

We want the xxxx part to be something like 0001. Now, let's invert K:

```
~K  = yyyy0000
```

where yyyy is the bitwise inverse of xxxx, and should look like 1110. So, once again, we can check for the trailing zero-bits and set them with `int L = (~K) | ((~K)-1);`. The result sould now be all one-bits if there was only one block of one-bits in the original number.

Now the special cases:

- If there was no one-bit at all in N, the result will also give all ones. As the one-bits block is missing, the result should be false, needing a special handling.
- A number consisting of just one block of one-bits will also result in all ones. But as the trailing zero-bits are missing, it should return false, needing a special handling as well, which just has to look at the last bit being zero.

So the code code look like:

```
private static boolean setBitFollowedByUnsetBits(int num) {
    if (num == 0) return false;
    if ((num & 1) == 1) return false;
    int invK = ~ (num | (num-1));
    int indicator = invK | (invK-1);
    return indicator == 0xffffffff;
}
```

Comment: seems it doesnt' work on sample: 3 (it returns ```true``` instead of ```false```)

Comment: @AlexanderPaderin The problem is ambiguous; it is unclear that 3 is meant to return `false`.

Comment: @Alexander I'll edit the answer to cover the case as explained.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff yep, looks great now. I've done some benchmarking and your method appears the fastest one as expected :)

Comment: greater score - better. ```benchmark1``` - my solution, ```benchmark2``` - Ralf's solution and ```benchmark3``` topic starter's solution (all of them previously checked for correctness):
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
MyBenchmark.benchmark1  thrpt   20   115.533 ±   6.273  ops/s
MyBenchmark.benchmark2  thrpt   20  2046.093 ± 105.604  ops/s
MyBenchmark.benchmark3  thrpt   20    22.764 ±   0.893  ops/s

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt Brian Kernigan's Algorithm
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/

a) Initialize count: = 0
b) If integer n is not zero

1. Do bitwise & with (n-1) and assign the value back to n

   { n: = n&(n-1) }
2. Increment count by 1
3. go to step b

c)  Else return count

As explained in the link above Subtraction of 1 from a number toggles all the bits (from right to left) till the rightmost set bit(including the rightmost set bit). So if we subtract a number by 1 and do bit-wise & with itself (n & (n-1)), we unset the rightmost set bit. If we do n & (n-1) in a loop and count the no of times loop executes we get the set bit count.

Comment: it will help in counting the number of set bits , how it will ensure that all set bits are followed by unset bits only

Comment: So in a number say like 110010110000 you want to return false if I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think that more efficient way is to do bitwise checking instead of `string -> integer` transformation and operating with strings.

```
private static boolean check(int value) {
    int h = SIZE - numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
    boolean one = false;
    boolean zero = false;
    for (int i = h - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int mask = 1 << i;
        if ((value & mask) == mask) {
            if (!zero) {
                one = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (one) {
                zero = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return one && zero;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
private static boolean setBitFollowedByUnsetBits(int num) {
    int withoutTrailingZeros = num >>> Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(num);
    return num != 0 && (withoutTrailingZeros & withoutTrailingZeros + 1) == 0;
}
```

This works because your problem is really to shift out the trailing zeros, which Java has a fast built in function for, then to test if the remaining number has all bits set (up to the most significant bit). You can do this with a bitwise and, as for any number `n`, `n & n + 1` is only `0` if `n` has all bits set (see below). I assume you don't want `0` to return `true` because it has no bits set, but you can remove the `num != 0 &&` if this isn't the case.

```
   111 // 7
& 1000 // 8
= 0000 // 0, so 7 has all bits set

   101 // 5
&  110 // 6
=  100 // 4, so 5 does not have all bits set
```

Edit: if the number must have some trailing zeros, you can also check for `withoutTrailingZeros != num` to be `true`.